# Android: Can't destroy threads in custom View

Tags: android, multithreading, view, timer, android-asynctask

I start by saying that I am a beginner in the Android world..

Application Structure:

The main activity is a AppCompatActivity with a DrawerLayout and a NavigationView.
Each item of the NavigationView has a custom “OnMenuItemClickListener” that will choose which Fragment to call using the following instruction:

```
f = new MyFragment();
/*set bundle*/
mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, f).commit();
```

There are some items that have to call a particular fragment (TableFragment), this will create (in onCreateView) a table and will fill it with some views (with different parameters depending by an array in the bundle, for simplicity I deleted them here):

```
TableRow tr;
CustomView cv;
tableLayout.removeAllViews();
for (int a = 0; a < myArray.size(); a=a+3) {
        tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
        for(int cvn = 0; cvn < 3; cvn++) {
            if(a+cvn < myArray.size()) {
                cv = new CustomView(getActivity(), myArray.get(a + cvn);
                tr.addView(cv);
            }
        }
        tableLayout.addView(tr);
}
```

My CustomView includes a FrameLayout with a ImageView and a TextView. In the constructor I create a timer which will call a AsyncTask on a fixed interval.

Method #1:

```
timer = new Timer();
timTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        asyncTask at = new asyncTask (parameters..);
        at.execute("");
    }
};
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timTask, 10, 500);
```

Method #2:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        asyncTask at = new asyncTask(parameters..);
        at.execute("");
    }
}, 10, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

The asyncTask will communicate with a plc and, for example, rotate the ImageView according to certain signals (so I can simply know if it’s working or not).

My problem is when I switch to another voice of the NavigationView and then came back to this Fragment. The table is properly created and filled with the Views (I can see the text), but every time the Timer starts later then the previous (the images are created and start their rotation later).
I suppose I should destroy the threads but I can’t understand where to insert the properly instructions to do that.
I tried, for example, in onDetachedFromWindow() in the single View the following instructions, obviously without many result:

```
@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        timTask.cancel();
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        this.removeAllViews();
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

It seems my problem is not the timer but the AsyncTask.
My table is filled with 28 Views and while this fragment is alive I can see all their timers ("Timer-1", "Timer-2", etc), then when I change fragment they disappear.

The AsyncTasks instead are always 9 ("AsyncTask#1", "AsyncTask#2", etc):

[Alive threads when my fragment is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LE06.png)

[Alive threads when I change fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrpPu.png)

I've tried with `this.cancel(true)` in the `onPostExecute()` of the task and by the parent fragment for each View `view.asyncTask.cancel(true)`

So, how can I destory theese Tasks?

Comment: in `onDestroy()` you can clear all the required things.

Comment: My View does not have a method onDestroy()  'CustomView extends LinearLayout'.. where should i use it? in the previous Fragment?